# Regex exclude hyphen as right endpoint of capture (VB.NET)

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I have the following string (in vb.net):

```
Dim data as String = "-- Compiled: Aug  6 2015 10:07:08 --\nanotherline--\n..."
```

I'd like the output of regex.match() to look like the following:

```
Aug  6 2015 10:07:08
```

I'm trying variations of this:

```
Regex.Match(data, "(?<=Compiled:\s)(.*)(?<!-)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString
```

but the best I can output is:

```
Aug  6 2015 10:07:08 --\nanotherline--\n...
```

How do I get regex to acknowledge the hyphen ("dash") character to stop matching?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't to need to use lookbehind at RHS, just use `negation` pattern:

```
Regex.Match(data, "(?<=Compiled:\s)([^-]*)\s-)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/7)

Comment: this one is my favorites, but how would I quickly remove the space before the hyphen, as well as the hyphen?

Comment: [You can use this: `(?<=Compiled:\s)([^-]*)\s-)`](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/7)

Comment: Thanks for the link to regex101

Answer (score 2):

You need to use positive lookahead with a non-greedy regex.

```
Regex.Match(data, "(?<=Compiled:\s).*?(?=\s*-)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=Compiled:\s)(.*?)(?=-{2})
```

Use a `lookahead` instead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/9